# Making a table from two vectors in R

Tags: r

So I have two vectors:

```
Totals_row <- c(211,52,93)
Totals_col <- c(116,141,99)
```

I want to take the first number from each vector and multiply it together then divide it by this number, Freq_tot <- 356.

Example: E(1,1) = (211*116)/356 = 68.75.
I want to make a table out of each of the possible values. I am sure there is a way to make of loop that will go through each iteration and add it into a empty matrix, the result should be a 3x3 matrix.

If anyone can help me with a faster way to do this in R than by doing it rigorously.

Comment: If I interpret the "each of the possible values" correctly: `outer(x, y) / sum(x)` (please show/describe the desired result more carefully). And please edit your title to something more explicit; "Making a table" is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with loops, you'll need two nested loops

```
Totals_row <- c(211,52,93)
Totals_col <- c(116,141,99)
results <- matrix(
   data = NA,
   nrow = length(Totals_row),
   ncol = length(Totals_col)
)
Freq_tot <- 356

for (i in seq_along(Totals_row)) {
   for (j in seq_along(Totals_col)) {
      results[i,j] <- Totals_row[i] * Totals_col[j] / Freq_tot
   }
}
```

---

You should consider Hendrik's comment though. Loops in R are not an efficient solution. I only posted the loops because it's what was asked.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
   with_loops = {
      for (i in seq_along(Totals_row)) {
         for (j in seq_along(Totals_col)) {
            results[i,j] <- Totals_row[i] * Totals_col[j] / Freq_tot
         }
      }
   },
   with_outer = outer(Totals_row, Totals_col) / Freq_tot
)
```

```
Unit: microseconds
       expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq    max neval
 with_loops 3045.3 3151.45 3549.642 3285.95 3679.9 9037.6   100
 with_outer    4.1    5.30   10.442   10.30   13.6   40.6   100
```

Comment: Holy Cow man, I've been. scratching my head all morning on trying to find a way to do this faster cuz I eventually want to do this with larger vectors. Thank you, the loop looks elegant.